# Using JAXB binding extensions in wsimport

Tags: java, jaxb, jax-ws, wsimport, jax-ws-customization

I know how to enable extensions in a plain JAXB bindings file - list them in the root element's `extensionBindingPrefixes`:

```xml
<jaxb:bindings 
    version="1.0"
    xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
    jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="xjc"
    ...>
```

However, a JAX-WS bindings file doesn't have anywhere to put this attribute.

```xml
<jaxws:bindings
    version="2.0"
    xmlns:jaxws="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxws"
    xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
    wsdlLocation="../wsdl/schema.wsdl"
    ...>
```

It cannot go in the root, nor in any of the nested `jaxb:bindings` elements.

How are you supposed to enable binding extensions?

---

Example command-line arguments used by jaxws-maven-plugin:2.4.1:

```sh
-keep
-s 'target/generated-sources/wsimport'
-d 'target/classes'
-encoding UTF-8
-extension
-Xnocompile
-B-XJsr303Annotations
-B-Xvalue-constructor
-B-Xinheritance
-b 'src/jaxws/bindings.xml'
'src/wsdl/schema.wsdl'
```

Comment: what versions of software are you using?

Comment: @KalpeshSoni jaxws-maven-plugin:2.3

Comment: you can specify *multiple* bindings file to `wsimport` using `-b` option. So having `extensionBindingPrefixes` in separate `jaxb` bindings file wouldn't help ?

Comment: @ulab No, that didn't seem to do anything. I assume it only applies to the child elements.

Comment: what error do you get? or it simply doesnt add  your interface?

Comment: @KalpeshSoni indeed, no errors. I know the xpaths etc are correct because things like jaxb:class name work fine. The extensions seem to be parsed (they fail if incorrect) but they don't do anything.

Comment: share the pom section?

Comment: @KalpeshSoni what are you hoping to see there?

Comment: What is the equivalent entry in maven for -XadditionalHeaders  in cmd ?

Comment: @AbdulRazakAK [read the documentation](http://www.mojohaus.org/jaxws-maven-plugin/wsimport-mojo.html)